# Phalcon dispatcher getParam default value is not set as expected

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm trying to make pagination for a listing page, and I'm having problems setting default value for $page with getParam method from dispatcher.

The URL is like this : (http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/page_number_here)

This is how I get page param from dispatcher

`$page = $this->dispatcher->getParam('page', 'int', 1);`

the problem is that when I put letters only (or nothing at all) for page, it doesn't set $page with 1 as I expect it to do, it sets it with an empty string.

Am I doing something wrong, is there something that I got it wrong on how it should work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Param methods in dispatcher will work only if you have named parameters defined in your [routing definitions](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/routing.html), what may happen to be a bit tricky.

I would recommend you to use [request](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/api/Phalcon_Http_Request.html) service:

```
$this->request->get('page', 'int', 1)
```

For this to work you will also be required to tweak your routing definitions because at this point Phalcon does not know where `page` param exists, but may be it will be a bit less complicated. You will find it out what approach suits you better.